# For $p,q\in\mathbb N^*$, if $\phi(p\,q)=(p-1)(q-1)$, then $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes

Tags: algebra-precalculus, totient-function

If $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, then [the Euler totient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) of their product $\phi(p\,q)$ is $(p-1)(q-1)$. What's a simple proof of the converse (restricted to strictly positive integers $p$ an $q$) ?

Full proposition:
$$\forall(p,q)\in(\mathbb N^\star)^2,\ \phi(p\,q)=(p-1)(q-1)\implies p\in\mathbb P∧q\in\mathbb P∧p\ne q$$

---

<sub>My original proposition was: $p_i\in\mathbb N^*, \phi(\prod p_i)=\prod(p_i-1)$ implies the $p_i$ are distinct primes. It was [disproved](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/9715081) by the counterexample $\phi(4\times3\times3)=3\times2\times2$.</sub>
<sub>The original motivation is [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/103540/555) in a crypto context. The proof I could make by contraposition considering the explicit factorization of $p$ and $q$ is rather laborious.</sub>

Comment: The converse is not true (which is why I was clarifying what you were trying to say, esp if you were introducing a different constraint).  EG $12 = \phi(36) = \phi(4 \times 3 \times 3) = 3 \times 2 \times 2$. $\quad$ Do you see how to build this using $ \phi(2^m) = 2^{m-1}, \phi(3^n) = 3^{n-1} \times 2$?

Comment: @Calvin Lin: indeed my original proposition is disproved by your counterexample. I have restricted to two integers. I leave my mistake and your refutation apparent. Thanks. A proof is now simpler (it's often easier to prove a true proposition :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p$, $q$ have a prime factor $k$ in common, then $k^2$ is a factor of $pq$, so $k$ is a factor of $\phi(pq)$. But $k$ cannot be a factor of $p-1$ or $q-1$. So, if $\phi(pq)=(p-1)(q-1)$, this is not possible and so $p$, $q$ are relatively prime and hence $\phi(pq) = \phi(p)\phi(q)$, but then $\phi(p)$ is at most $p-1$ and $\phi(q)$ at most $q-1$, so they must have these values, and $p$, $q$ are prime.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Clarification: "So $p$, $q$ are relatively prime" makes use of the hypothesis $\phi(p\,q)=(p-1)(q-1)$. After it's established that $p$ and $q$ are prime, $p\ne q$ also follows from this hypothesis.

Comment: Yes: I've clarified my solution.